# Can I split a 200v range circuit into two 110v circuits?

Tags: wiring

I am doing a flip and there was a stove with 220 40A  and  I think 6 gage wire in the location where I'm putting an island.  I want to split off the 220 and run one hot to 3 110v outlets on the island and the other hot to an outlet for a microwave both using 14 gauge wire. Do you see a problem?

Comment: Don't just guess at wire size. Make sure you know exactly what you are working with before you dive in to make changes.

Comment: Does your state's electrical code require you to provision 40A or 50A service to a potential future electric range?

Comment: Does the 220V/40A cable have a ground wire (4 wires)?

Comment: When you say split. How do you propose to split it? How do you propose breaker protection for the new circuits? Little known fact: 15 and 20 amp plug-in breakers only accept wiring up to #8 wiring. Meaning a #6 won't fit.

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician -- that's easy to fix with a pigtail in the panel though

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because of the following primary reason. The large gauge wire that feeds to that point is most certainly fed from a breaker in the breaker panel with a rating of 30A. If a short or failure occurred in your added wiring, added outlets or any thing plugged into those outlets there could be current flow well in excess of what the small 14AWG wire can safely carry. The wire would overheat, melt insulation and combust any adjacent materials. The result would be a serious fire, occupant safety concern and expensive property damage.

The proper way to do something like this is to run the appropriate sized wire back to the power panel and install the suitably sized breaker (15A for 14AWG or 20A for 12AWG).

You could possibly replace the existing 40A breaker with a 15A breaker so that the large gauge wire is current limited to 15A but before considering to do that check with your local code enforcement agency to see if that is allowed. As a bare minimum such replacement should always label the large wires at each end to indicate that it feeds a circuit with 14AWG wire.

There are a couple of other things to consider here too:

1. Check the microwave ratings carefully. Some units may very well require a 20A circuit with 12AWG wire.
2. If that existing 40A circuit was one that was installed some longer time in the past and terminated into a three prong outlet then there is unlikely to have been a safety ground wire in the cable back to the breaker box. You will not be able to connect outlets up to the old three wire power cable that does not have a safety ground as it is now required by code for any new added wiring and outlets to have a safety ground connection. This alone would require running new power cable with the safety ground back to the power panel.

Comment: You are allowed to use 6 AWG wire on a 20A circuit.

Comment: Be aware that microwaves suck considerably more power than the rating on the package. That's microwave output watts, not electrical at the socket watts.

Comment: Almost all microwaves on the market in the U.S. are 15 amp corded models. I have installed larger commercial units but they are rare.

Answer (score 0):

This split can be done to code if it is a 4 wire feed to the existing location but for kitchen countertop you need 20 amp 12 awg wire. First a new. 20 amp double pole breaker would be needed in the panel creating a multi wire branch circuit. Next in the panel you would pigtail each hot to a #12 wire then to the breaker, it is legal to use larger wire but 6 won't fit a 20 amp breaker. It is legal to splice or make the pigtail in the breaker panel. Next an accessible junction box will be needed to make the junction in the kitchen to splice the #12 to the #6. I would use a deep 4×4 box add a mud ring and that could be the outlet for the stove igniter (I am guessing you are converting to gas) in every state I have worked 1 gas port or electrical ~40 amp circuit has been required. If you are pulling a new feed for a larger "range" the junction box could just have a cover plate located behind the range and this would be legal. If the 40 amp is a 3 wire you would only be able to run a single circuit.

Answer (score 0):

### *Maybe*.

First, you need to see if your city requires you *provision* 40A or 50A service at the location to power an electric range/oven.  Sometimes that must be installed even if the current oven is gas.  If the city requires that, then *leave it alone* and run new cables for your new circuits.

Second, you need to see if the existing cable is 3-wire or 4-wire.  In a 3-wire setup, the bared wires are the **neutral**.  In a 4-wire setup, there is a white wire for neutral, and a bared wire for **ground**.  In the case of a 3-wire setup, I highly recommend retrofitting a ground while you have everything opened up; that will qualify it as a 4-wire setup.

If you remain with a 3-wire setup, you cannot do anything useful with these wires, except power an electric range, and even that has some safety issues (it is technically "leeeegal" but if a wire breaks, this system becomes deadly, and normally the system has enough redundancy that failed wires aren't deadly.

### If you have a 4-wire setup

You will be able to wire something up called a "multi-wire branch circuit" or MWBC.  Now, you should know MWBCs are all but obsolete owing to the requirement for AFCI and/or GFCI breakers, which don't play all that well with MWBCs.  But if you're willing to source 2-pole AFCI and/or GFCI breakers if needed, this can work.

In this case, you would use a 20A 2-pole breaker.  Toss out your #14 wire, it's not much use in kitchen wiring.  Your receptacle circuit **absolutely must** be 20A.  The microwave circuit *could* be 15A, but that in turn would require a lopsided 15A/20A breaker. You can assemble that with two plain breakers and a handle-tie, but it'll be absolutely impossible if AFCI or GFCI enters the picture.  So the right choice is make both circuits 20A.  That means you must be using 12AWG wire, #14 is not acceptable.

The junction between the big feeder and the two circuits must be inside a junction box, and you must be able to demonstrate in front of the inspector that you can fully access the junction box cover without tools, so you can't mud it up behind drywall or put a cabinet in front of it.  Putting an oven in front of it is fine, if you can slide it out for the inspector after the kitchen is finished.

Circuit 1 for the receptacles ties its hot, neutral and ground into the feeder's Hot #1, its neutral and its ground.  (remember you need a 4-wire grounded circuit to do this).  Your next stop **must** be a GFCI protective device if that isn't already present in the service panel.  It can be a GFCI deadfront. You come off that device's `LOAD` terminals and hop in the normal way to a string of plain receptacles, which must be marked "GFCI protected".

Circuit 2 for the microwave ties its hot, neutral and ground into the feeder's hot #2, its neutral and its ground.  You don't need a GFCI protective device on a dedicated circuit for a built-in microwave where there'd be no possibility of plugging in a kitchen countertop load, so you're done :)